# Use MacPorts PHP-FPM instead of from build

Tags: php, macports, apache2.4, macos-mojave, php-7.3

I've used MacPorts to install `apache2`, `php73` and `php73-fpm` on MacOS Mojave. I've updated by `.bash_profile` to reflect the new MacPorts paths like so:

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

I've refreshed my `.bash_profile` by running:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Running `which php` and `which httpd` in Terminal both output the correct paths:

```
/opt/local/bin/php
/opt/local/sbin/httpd
```

And running `php -v` and `httpd -v` both indicate that the MacPorts Apache and PHP are running.

However, I can't switch to the MacPorts `php73-fpm` that I installed. `which php-fpm` still returns the default OS build path:

```
/usr/sbin/php-fpm
```

How can I get the MacPorts `php73-fpm` running instead of the build `php-fpm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do is to check port's content:

```
$ port contents php73-fpm
Port php73-fpm contains:
  /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.php73-fpm.plist
  /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.php73-fpm/org.macports.php73-fpm.plist
  /opt/local/etc/php73/php-fpm.conf.default
  /opt/local/etc/php73/php-fpm.d/www.conf.default
! /opt/local/sbin/php-fpm73
  ...
```

So, as we can see port's executable is called **php-fpm73**, not php73-fpm